# Highcharts and Windows 8 app (WinJS)

Tags: highcharts

Hi I want to use highcharts in my Windows 8 app (HTML5 and JavaScript) but...

```
Exception. line 35, column 471 en ms-appx://c4c6faa3-6deb-457c-a894-94774f7ba6a1/herramientas/estadistica/js/highcharts/highcharts.js
0x800a139e - Error in runtime in JavaScript: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
```

The jquery library used is a [modified version](http://www.incloud.de/2012/08/windows-8-using-jquery-for-app-development).

Basically [I want to see this in my W8 app](http://jsfiddle.net/Gve9F/3/), but I can't.

Thanks.

Comment: Error 13: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13, essentially the div in your `renderTo:` isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and apologies to Mark for the poor structure of my post, I'm new here.

I be sure that the div if there but I will make sure of that, i thought could not use Highcharts in Win8 app.